# How was early Indian history re-constructed?

Tags: india, ancient-india

I heard that ancient Indian history was reconstructed from Iranian/Persian and Chinese texts that survived til today. Is this true? Also what were the other major sources used?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question, but please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help] center, and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: It might  help to narrow this down to some specific events or facts.

Answer (score 6):

We don't have *any* decipherable native writing from the subcontinent until [the 3rd Century BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edicts_of_Ashoka). This means anything we know about what was going on in the area prior to the [Maurya Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurya_Empire) has to be derived either from the records of neighboring civilizations, or via archeology.

Greek accounts are particularly useful during the periods of time that Greek armies were in possession of portions of the Indus Valley (about 326-70 BCE). This is because Greek histories were highly-prized in the West, and thus widely copied, which means many of them survived to modern times.

The Chinese tended to have a strong interest in the goings-on in neighboring areas beyond their borders, based on a healthy sense of self-preservation. They also held great reverence for their histories and, helped out by their relatively continuous culture, many of those records survived to modern times as well.

It appears that even when Indians did develop native literature, most of their [preserved manuscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm-leaf_manuscript) seem primarily interested in things like (Hindu) Philosophy, poetry, and Grammar. All worthy priorities for preservation to be sure, but History does not appear to have been among those priorities.

This is sub-optimal of course, and most of the local details not available in outside accounts have to be filled in via the tools of archeology. But we work with what we have.

Comment: Are there any specific Bactrian histories that cover the region (and India)?

Comment: @gktscrk looks like a well scoped and separate question

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Is it? It seems to be directly what is referred to above with "Greek accounts are particularly useful..."?

Comment: @gktscrk - Well,that's effectively the state I was talking about in the latter portion of the age range I got. For example, Strabo's Geographica was written around 20BC, and included some Indian information. However, Greek-speaking Bactria had fallen to the Scythians a generation or two earlier, which meant the Indo-Greeks had lost all effective contact with the Greek world. Our knowledge of them thereafter appears to derive more and more from inferences drawn from surviving coinage.